# BlackBerry Cascades sending email without user interaction

Tags: cascade, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

i would like to send email without user interaction...means user just need to press a button and mail automatically get send to the particular person....

and also how to get information like device id, OS version , currently running/installed apps in blackberry z10?

if any body know about this please reply with code or some good example.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the documentation for Cascades is available from BlackBerry ([Cascades API](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/)) with details for all of your items:

- Sending Email/Messages: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/pim/messages.html
- Device ID/PIN/Serial: [http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*device*_hardwareinfo.html#property-pin](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html#property-pin)
- OS Version/Platform Info: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/platform_info.html
- Hardware Info: [http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*device*_hardwareinfo.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__device__hardwareinfo.html)
- Installed/Running Apps: (haven't found yet, it might not be available)
- Location: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/location.html
- BBM: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/app_integration_bbm.html
  etc.

For any items not currently available they can be tracked in the public [Cascades Roadmap](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/).

*(bear with me, I'm linking in all the items 1 by 1)*

Comment: if u check the code in this link http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/pim/messages.html only recipient details are mentioned but where is the sender user name and password? i need to send mail using my id and password and also code is giving error for messagebuilder object that no matching call to MessageBuilder(); what to  do?